# How to create a list with two if conditions in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am unsure as to how I list more than one variable. See below.

Syntax I have right now:
list *varname* if  *varname_a*==1 & *varname_b*==1

Comment: The title and the body of the question don't seem to match.

Answer (score 1):

The question is how to `list` more than one variable and the answer is to tell Stata which variables you want:

```
list varname_a varname_b if varname_a==1 & varname_b==1
list c d e if varname_a==1 & varname_b==1
```

That could be all of them:

```
list if varname_a==1 & varname_b==1

list
```

That is all documented under `help list`.

The title on the other hand refers to two `if` conditions, but that's a puzzle because the text itself gives the answer: use a single compound `if` condition. `if` never occurs twice in a single command.

Comment: I am trying to list an associated number if the observation is they have both qualify for event_a and event_b.

Comment: I think that's the kind of code you had in your question, so where is the problem? Why not edit your question to give a reproducible example?

Comment: Stata gives back "." for missing. When I tried yesterday I was receiving a syntax error. If there is nothing for the list, would it state "no observations"?

Comment: That's not a reproducible example in either case. `list` would say nothing if there were no observations satisfying the condition stated. Try it: `list if 42 == 43`. That is never true, so nothing is listed.

Comment: I could say much more, I suspect, if only I knew what specific problems you were facing.

Comment: I achieved what I needed with: tab varname_a if varname_b==1 & varname_b==1

Comment: `if varname_b == 1 & varname_b == 1` can be simplified to `if varname_b == 1`. More seriously, if you never show real code and the real problems arising in reproducible examples, you won't get good, fast replies. Do study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve